# what does the dereference symbol do to an array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, dynamic

```
int cols = 2;

    int *p[2];

    *p = new int[cols];

    *(p+1) = new int[cols];
```

I have this very simple code however I don't understand why the * is required in `*p = new int[cols];`normally when declaring a 1d array its simply `p=new int[cols];But in a 2d array you need the * what is it doing??`also when I `cout<< *p` I get cccccc what is the meaning of this?

Answer (score 1):

The code is just written really poorly. It may be clearer when you write it like this:

```
using Thing = int *;

Thing make_thing(int n) {  return new int[n]; }

// ...

Thing p[2];
p[0] = make_thing(cols);
p[1] = make_thing(cols);
```

There's a general language rule that says that `A[B]` is identical to `*(A + B)`, and because of that the two code snippets mean the same thing.

Comment: Its the standard syntax for declaring a dynamic array I'm just not sure why you need that extra dereference symbol for 2d arrays and how an array of pointer works exactly

Comment: @lolsharp: I thought the last sentence in my answer addresses that. Note that my code does *not* use a dereference symbol, and it is identical to your code.

Comment: no I understand that A[B] is identical to *(A + B),  my question is why you declare a 2d dynamic array like this int *p[2];
 
 *p = new int[cols]; but a 1d array like this p=new int[cols];

Comment: It's not a "2d dynamic array". It's a 1-D static array of (2) pointers (`Thing`s), and each pointer points to the first element of a dynamic 1-D array.